# How to return tags in HTML if the content contains certain string using libraries in python?

Tags: javascript, python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to extract all information in "Discography" section in this wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beatles
How can I check which tag is "Please Please Me" under in HTML?

I am using Requests and BeautifulSoup libraries in python, but haven't found any code.

Please give me any help, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-work-with-web-data-using-requests-and-beautiful-soup-with-python-3

https://gist.github.com/bradmontgomery/1872970

https://www.fernandomc.com/posts/using-requests-to-get-and-post/

Those sites will help to achieve what you want. If you facing anymore issue, ask again.